# Missing js for openfaces tree table

Tags: java, richfaces, jsf-1.2, openfaces

While trying to incorporate RichFaces with OpenFaces in a tree table, and it doesn't display any expand collapse buttons. It turned out that some of the js are not loaded, which might be the cause of it.

**JSF code is as follows:**

```
<o:treeTable var="o">
                        <o:dynamicTreeStructure nodeChildren="#{bean.originNodeChildren}"
                                                nodeHasChildren="#{bean.originHasChildren()}"/>
                        <o:treeColumn expandedToggleImageUrl="/img/toggle-expand-light.png"
                                      collapsedToggleImageUrl="img/toggle-collapse-light.png">
                            <h:outputText value="#{o.description}"/>
                        </o:treeColumn>
                    </o:treeTable>
```

Bean code is being triggered correctly (including hasChildren method).

**JS exceptions:**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (/openFacesResources/META-INF/resources/openfaces/util/ajaxUtil-2.1.EA1.1143.js)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (/openFacesResources/META-INF/resources/openfaces/util/util-2.1.EA1.1143.js)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (/openFacesResources/META-INF/resources/openfaces/tableUtil-2.1.EA1.1143.js)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (/openFacesResources/META-INF/resources/openfaces/table/table-2.1.EA1.1143.js)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (/openFacesResources/META-INF/resources/openfaces/table/treeTable-2.1.EA1.1143.js)
```

Using *OpenFaces version 2.0 and RichFaces version 3.3.3.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is needed to configure resource filter for open faces in web.xml and the job is done. Something like:

```
public class OpenFacesResourceFilter extends ResourceFilter {
    // -- Fields --

    // -- Methods --
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try{
            super.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            Throwable parent = e.getCause();
            if(parent!=null && parent instanceof ServletException) {
                throw (ServletException) parent;
            } else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have not declared the OpenFaces resource filter in the application's xml file indeed. Here's an excerpt from documentation on how a filter can be declared (note that you don't have to create any Java classes for this filter yourself):

```
  <!-- FILTER FOR PROCESSING INTERNAL OPENFACES RESOURCES -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>ResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.openfaces.util.ResourceFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <!-- MAPPING FOR OPENFACES RESOURCE FILTER -->
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

See the [Installation](http://wiki.openfaces.org/display/OF/Installation+and+Configuration+2.x#InstallationandConfiguration2.x-Installation) section, and the [Resource Filter Optimization](http://wiki.openfaces.org/display/OF/Installation+and+Configuration+2.x#InstallationandConfiguration2.x-ResourceFilterOptimization) sections in OpenFaces 2.0 documentation.